# Deal with resolution changed while decoding?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG with C++ to read frames and decode them from RTSP Stream on IP Camera.

Anything is ok, but while decoding, I try to change stream resolution config on IP Camera (ex: change from 1280x720 to 1920x1080).

The result is `av_read_frame()` in while loop still read successful next frames (with new resolution) without error. So I can not detect that change to reinit buffer or reconnect stream to update other stream's information.

`av_read_frame()` will read an AVPacket, If I can read resolution info in the AVPacket, then I can detect that change and reinit buffer. But I can't see any resolution info in AVPacket struct.

Someone can help me, how to detect resolution change while reading and decoding stream?

UPDATE

I'm using many codecs as H264 and H265/H265+. This case happened with all 3 codecs above.

In many cases I also store the AVPacket for later playback, so there's no need for decode. I need to detect the resolution change immediately to be able to properly build header information to store on the HDD.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using the `av_parser_parse2()` function to parse information such as `Resolution` from `AVPacket`, and compare it to the old values, to detect the change and then reconnect it again.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

In band resolution changes can not be detected by `av_read_frame()` because `av_read_frame()` does not parse the frame, It only reads the data from the stream and places it into a buffer. You will need to use a bitstreram parser, or send the frame to the decoder (if the decoder supports resolution changes). Every codec is different however, so I cant give you more information unless I know what codec you are using.

Comment: You need to start parsing bitstreams, and every codec will be different. You are entering a whole world of pain.

Comment: An alternative is to reset every key frame, but then you have a container problem.

Comment: Base on your answer, I have more information to search google, and I've solved this isse. Thank you :)